# Apple Script to access elements of the Context Menu for a file

Tags: user-interface, applescript, contextmenu, finder, uielement

I was able to get the context menu up with applescript 
tell perform action "AXShowMenu"

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder" tell window {window name} tell splitter group 1 tell splitter group 1 UI elements tell scroll area 1 UI elements tell group 1 UI elements tell image {filename} perform action "AXShowMenu" end tell end tell end tell end tell end tell end tell
```

This got the menu up. But I am not able to access any of the menu items. How can I access menu items for a file in finder?

Comment: tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
 tell window {window name}
  tell splitter group 1
   tell splitter group 1
    UI elements
    tell scroll area 1
     UI elements
     tell group 1
      UI elements
      tell image {filename}
       perform action "AXShowMenu"
      end tell
     end tell
    end tell
   end tell
  end tell
 end tell

I am not able to get the menu items after I click on AXShowMenu

Answer (score 0):

You can use keystroke to select the menu item:

```
set filename to "test.jpg"
tell application "Finder" to activate
delay 0.2
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        -- set theTarget to value of attribute "AXFocusedUIElement"
        set theTarget to group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        tell theTarget
            tell image filename to perform action "AXShowMenu"
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "open"
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```